# Dimensions of the co-domain of the graph defining a $k$-manifold in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

In [Shifrin's GU Math 3500 course online](https://youtu.be/TrCBN4IE0Wc) he gives the following definition of manifold:

> We say $M\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold if in a neighborhood of each point it can represented as a graph of a $C^1$ function  $\phi:U\to \mathbb R^{\color{red}{n-k}},$ for an open set $U$ in one of the standard coordinate $k$-planes.

I would like a simple explanation as to why the function is from the open set to $\mathbb R^{n-k}$. Why $n-k?$

For example a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ can be projected on the plane $xy$.  In this case $n=3$, the manifold is $k=2$, but the map is not on $n-k=1$, but rather on $\mathbb R^2$ - the plane $xy.$

Perhaps the conceptual hurdle has to do with a superficial "conflict" with [this definition](https://youtu.be/w1FaAu0SL-w?t=6m37s):

[image]

in which the mapping is to $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: The $2$-sphere is locally the graph of a function like $(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\in\mathbb R$..

Comment: The graph of such $\phi$ lies on $\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, as desired.

Comment: The graph of a function $f:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^d$ is the $k$-dimensional subset $\{ (x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb R^k\} \subset \mathbb R^{k+d}$; so in order to get a $k$-dimensional graph in $\mathbb R^n$ we need to choose $d=n-k$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis So $n$ is the ambient space, which in the case of a sphere, it would be $\mathbb R^3$. The sphere is a $2$-dim manifold, and hence, $k=2$, leaving $d=3-2=1.$ This means that there are $2$ free variables and $1$ pivot variable (?). Do you have an illustration?

Comment: Right, 2 free variables, 1 dependent variable. I don't have an illustration to link offhand, but the example given by @rldias is exactly the case of the sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ - it's locally the graph of the function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R : f(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Anthony Carapetis:

> The graph of a function $f:\mathbb R^k\to \mathbb R^d$ is the $k$-dimensional subset $\{(x,f(x)):x\in \mathbb R^k\}\subset \mathbb R^{k+d};$ so in order to get a $k$-dimensional graph in $\mathbb R^n$ we need to choose $d=n−k.$
>
> [my f-u ?] So $n$ is the [ambient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_space), which in the case of a [2-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), it would be $\mathbb R^3.$ The sphere is a $2$-dim manifold, and hence, $k=2$, leaving $d=3−2=1.$ This means that there are $2$ free variables and $1$ pivot variable?
>
> $2$ free variables, $1$ dependent variable. The example given by @rldias is exactly the case of the sphere in $R^3$ - it's locally the graph of the function $f:\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R:f(x,y)=\sqrt{1−x^2−y^2}.$

---

Just to make sure there is no lingering misunderstanding, I have tried to illustrate the concept in this plot of the $2$ sphere, which hopefully encapsulates the comments accurately:

[image]

I tend to think that the problem visualizing was in the surface (2D) nature of the open set around the point $P$ (in red), which doesn't preclude the function from the patch on the *$k=2$ standard coordinate* system in purple (on the $xy$ plane) to the neighborhood of $P$ from being a map $\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R^1.$

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Does it check out? (Thank you for the great lectures online!)

Comment: The coordinate patch is in fact a map (here just given by projection onto the $xy$-plane) from an open subset of the manifold to an open set of $\Bbb R^2$.  Since we're working with submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$, we don't need the abstract topological manifold definition (with overlaps of charts, etc.). Plus, we have the full power of the inverse and implicit function theorems because we're working with $C^1$ (or smooth) manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. Can I infer that the drawing is incorrect?

Comment: The drawing is fine. The upper hemisphere is the graph of the real-valued function you indicated. Any graph of a (smooth) function $\Bbb R^k\to \Bbb R^\ell$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold (for any $\ell$). Remember that the dimension of a manifold is different from the ambient dimension.